# How to find the MLE for two Dirichlet distributions with same mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing, dirichlet-distribution

I have samples from two groups. Samples from each group follow a Dirichlet distribution. The two Dirichlet distributions have the same mean but different precision. How to find the MLE of mean and two precisions?

Comment: are the group information of the observations known? Also specify the dirichlet distribution (K)

Comment: Have you googled 'Estimating a Dirichlet distribution'? [Tom Minka has a technical note](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/dirichlet/minka-dirichlet.pdf) discussing a technique for doing this.

Comment: The group information of the observations is known.

I read Tom Minka's note. It does not address this situation.

Comment: @user20094, I dont know what you mean by "group information of the observations is known". Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote how to do this in my dissertation work.  Minka's notes are actually quite helpful.  If you take a look at the procedures to obtain the mle of the mean and precision parameters in an iteratice way, it can be modified slightly to obtain the mle under the null hypothesis that the means of two ind. Dirichlet are equal while having seperate precisions. Just tack on an extra likelihood with the appropriate parameterization and follow Minka's steps.